# Automatically connecting two columns from different Excel Workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking to connect two columns from different workbooks on Excel.

Say:
Workbook 1 contains data from columns A to D, and every month person A updates column C.

I want the updates from Column C in Workbook 1 to get updated in Column D in Workbook 2. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [external references](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f).

Just open both workbooks, select column D in workbook 2, type `=`, go to the other workbook and select column C. You'll end up with a formula like

```
=[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$C:$C
```

[image]